# Applying L'Hôpital's rule on this function

Tags: limits

$f(x)=(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}-x$
I have to find the limit of f(x) as $x$ approaches infinity.
How do I apply L'Hôpital's rule here?
I tried multiplying the first term by $\frac {(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}} {(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}}$ to try to reduce the whole thing to a fraction but that didn't lead to anything. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:**

$$\begin{align}(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}-x&=\left((x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}-x\right)\left(\frac{(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}+x}{(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}+x}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{8x+20}{(x^2+8x+20)^{0.5}+x}\left(\frac{1/x}{1/x}\right)\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

I would multiply $f(x)$ by $\dfrac{(x^2 + 8x + 20)^{1/2} + x}{(x^2 + 8x + 20)^{1/2} + x}$

Then you have $\lim_\limits{x\to \infty}\dfrac{8x + 20}{(x^2 + 8x + 20)^{1/2} + x}$ and L'Hopital's is not necessary.